# How to write a regular expression to validate the format of an amount?

Tags: javascript

I have this code, in on keypress:

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.0-9]/g,'');
```

I want that only 4 digit can be entered before "." and 2 digit after "."

Comment: Does that mean you *have* to enter 4 digits before a . and 2 digits after it? Or can you enter *up to* 4 before and 2 after?

Comment: do want to cut wihtout warning? are the number always exactly 4 and 2 digits long?

Comment: If it is No security check you could start with maxlength attribute in the Input field

Comment: For variable length before the comma: /^[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{2}$/
For fixed length, just drop the "1,".

Answer (score 2):

Here's a regex which allows 1-4 digits before and 1-2 digits after the dot.

```
/\d{1,4}\.\d{1,2}/g
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to force 0000.00 then

```
/\d{4}\.\d{2}/
```

if the size of the groups are optional see Sn0opys answer

> \d - is a digit and the same as is [0-9]
>
> {x[,y]} x is the minimum and maximum count if [,y] is not specified.
>   if y is specified then x is the minimum count and y the maximum count
>   that shall be checked